# C# Swashbuckle - Webhook and Callbacks

Tags: c#, callback, webhooks, swashbuckle

I’m trying to implement Swashbuckle documentation for my Webhook Callbacks and have found the following GitHub https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/976

After adding this to my project I get the error

*Could not resolve reference: Could not resolve pointer: /components/schemas/WebhookPayload does not exist in document*

Does anyone know how to fix this issue or can anyone suggest how to implement Webhook documentation in C# Swashbuckle